# Django static jquery pip install won't load

Tags: jquery, python, django, pip

Following along [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-static-jquery/2.1.4)

I successfully ran:

```
pip install django-static-jquery==2.1.4
```

However, I cannot get the static content to be served in Django properly.  I have a simple html page:

```
<html>   
     {% load staticfiles %}  
     {% static 'static_jquery/js/jquery.js' %}
</html>
```

per the web page.  All that ends up happening is my HTML simply spits out this:

```
/static/static_jquery/js/jquery.js
```

instead of actually loading the library.  I am using the default Django roll out so I am curious what it is I am missing in this process.

settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = ( ...  
        django_static_jquery,
)
```

includes of just 'jquery' do not work as proposed in other questions.

Comment: @J0HN yes.  Will update my question shortly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, `{% static %}` is just for outputting a URL. If you want to load the javascript file, just do:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'static_jquery/js/jquery.js' %}"></script>
    </head>
</html>
```

Comment: this now results in a 200 thank you!  I cannot yet accept this answer.  However, does this also work in non DEBUG mode?  i.e. production

Comment: Yes it does, but you'll need to [`collecstatic`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#django-admin-collectstatic) in production.

Comment: Seem to be having a slight issue now where somehow jquery can find no ids when I do a simple hello world.  Does this sound like something you have experienced?

Comment: Since this is a whole different issue (javascript-related), I suggest you do some research to find the answer , then open a new question on Stack Overflow with relevant code.

Comment: yeah I just found it turns out I didn't wrap the function correctly somehow

Answer (score 2):

Did you added this to the installed apps?

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    # ...

    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django_static_jquery',

    # ...
)
```